# Боковое меню android studio

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Хотел попросить ссылку на подробную инструкцию написания бокового меню, программирование под android в среде программирования android studio. Хочу сделать боковое меню, но никак не получается, находил на хабре инструкцию по написанию Navigation Drawer, но постоянно при запуске на эмуляторе выдает кучу ошибок, поэтому прошу помощи. Посоветуйте хорошую инструкцию по написании бокового меню.

Comment: Все понял не то подумал, поставил.

Comment: Есть у кого-нибудь еще варианты реализации, хочу попробовать и изучить как можно больше.)

Comment: на офф сайте смотрели? http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) нравится!

Comment: Ну да, вариант хороший, спасибо. Буду его пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

В последней Android Studio есть макет активити, который вы выбираете при создании проекта NavigationViewAcitivity, создайте такой проект и вам будет всё понятно.

Comment: Штука нужная, но для лучшего понимания хотелось бы инструкцию, как делать боковое меню руками с нуля.